# What segment of .o file contains function xyz?

Tags: elf, objdump

Consider a question **"Which segment of abc.o contains function foo()?"**

Is this the same question as

**"What section of ELF contains this function foo()?"**

Sorry .. i know this is very silly. I am a bit confused here.

Comment: ELF is a spec, and/or an implementation of that spec.  I'm pretty sure no section of either of them contains a function called `foo()`.</pedantry>  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much the same, at least assuming the .o file in question is an ELF file.

Answer (score 0):

Segments are part of loadable ELF file. No segments reside inside object files as no load address is available yet. Usually, one segment contains one or more sections. Code section